# WP Query - posts only by specific user

Tags: wp-query

I have problem. I need insert this wp query 
`$cust_loop = new WP_Query( 'author=123' );`
But I cant remove the `$args` from $cust_loop = new WP_Query($args);
`And i tried everything like`$cust_loop = new WP_Query($args, 'author=123');`

I want show posts only by specific user, Thanks :)

---

```
if($typecount>0) {
    class con_latest_reviews extends WP_Widget {
        function con_latest_reviews() {
            /* Widget settings. */
            $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'Continuum Latest Reviews', 'description' => 'Displays a single review type by most recent or highest rated. Add multiple widgets for each review type.' );
            /* Widget control settings. */
            $control_ops = array( 'width' => 250, 'height' => 350, 'id_base' => 'con_latest_reviews' );
            /* Create the widget. */
            $this->WP_Widget( 'con_latest_reviews', 'Continuum Latest Reviews', $widget_ops, $control_ops );
        }   
        function widget( $args, $instance ) {

            extract( $args );

            /* User-selected settings. */
            $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title'] );
            $sort = $instance['sort'];
            $reviewtype = $instance['reviewtype'];
            $numreviews = $instance['numreviews'];

            //get review type for More link URL purpose
            $reviewtypeurl = $reviewtype;
            if($reviewtypeurl=="game") $reviewtypeurl="video-game";

            if($sort=="highest-rated") {
                $feedsort="meta_value";
                $metakey="&meta_key=Rating";
            } else {
                $feedsort="date";
                $metakey="";
            } ?>

            <div class="tabdiv reviews <?php echo $reviewtype; ?>">

                <?php

                /* Before widget (defined by themes). */
                echo $before_widget;

                /* Title of widget (before and after defined by themes). */
                if ( $title ) { ?>                  
                    <?php echo str_replace('<h2 class="gentesque">','<h2 class="gentesque">',$before_title); ?>
                        <div class="icon <?php echo $reviewtype; ?>">&nbsp;</div>
                        <?php echo $title; ?>
                    <?php echo $after_title; ?>
                <?php } 

                /* HTML output */
                ?>

                <ul>
                    <?php // setup the query
                    $args='&posts_per_page='.$numreviews.'_reviews&order=DESC&orderby='.$feedsort.$metakey;                             
                    $cust_loop = new WP_Query($args); 
                    if ($cust_loop->have_posts()) : while ($cust_loop->have_posts()) : $cust_loop->the_post(); $postcount++;
                        // if we're sorting by rating and this item does not have a rating, hide it
                        $rating = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "Rating", $single = true); 
                        if(($rating && $feedsort=="meta_value") || ($feedsort!="meta_value")) {                                     
                            $ratings = con_setup_rating($rating); //setup the ratings array 
                            ?>
                            <li>                                                                                    

                                <?php con_show_rating($ratings[0], $ratings[1], $ratings[2]); // show the stars or hearts ?>    

                                <a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>                                              

                            </li>

                        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: See here - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/175746/42702

Answer (score 2):

If all you need to do is add that extra parameter, just concatenate it on to the end of `$args`. (As a side note: I recommend using an array for args instead of the query string method as I find it much more readable.)

```
<?php
....
$args='&posts_per_page='.$numreviews.'_reviews&order=DESC&orderby='.$feedsort.$metakey.'&author=123';
....
```